# \includepdf and \rightmark do not work with each other?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pdfpages

I have several pdf files available, and now I wish to combine them into 1 file, which I call "attachment bundle".
I want to put a table of content at the beginning, showing the starting page of each of the single pdf files in the "attachment bundle".
I also wish to add a header, to show the global pages of the "attachment bundle". 
So far so good.

However, when I tried to include the name of each file (e.g. Curriculum vitae, Personal Statement) in the header using `\rightmark`, the titles (i.e. section names) do not show up. How to fix this?

Below is my code. Sorry it's a bit messy.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 headsep=28mm
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{20mm}
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{35mm}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Attachment bundle, Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\addto\captionsUKenglish{% Replace "UKenglish" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Attachment list}% Change the title of Contents 
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pagecommand={\section[Curriculum vitae]{}}, scale=1, pages=1]{Sections/2020_04_19_cv.pdf}
\includepdf[pagecommand={}, scale=1, pages=2-]{Sections/2020_04_19_cv.pdf}
 % to avoid an empty page

\includepdf[pagecommand={\section[Personal Statement]{}}, scale=1, pages=1]{Sections/2020_04_19_Personal_Statement.pdf} 
\includepdf[pagecommand={}, scale=1, pages=2-]{Sections/2020_04_19_Personal_Statement.pdf}

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to interact with the elements of the included PDF, you're probably better off including their corresponding `.tex` files with [`\input` or `\include`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/), assuming they're TeX documents; if they're not, you'll probably have to set these things manually in your main `.tex` file with e.g. `\renewcommand{\rightmark}{something}`.

Comment: I defined `\rightmark` manually and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In twoside mode \section sets the left mark not the right one:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 headsep=28mm
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{20mm}
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{35mm}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Attachment bundle, Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pagecommand={\section[Curriculum vitae]{}}, scale=1, pages=1]{example-image}
\includepdf[pagecommand={}, scale=1, pages=2-6]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]